# Page content not visible on Android in landscape

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have been visiting StackOverFlow for a good while now to find all kinds of solutions to problems I run into in coding, so I figured this would be the place to post when I ran into a problem I can't find a solution for.

I changed the media queries for my site yesterday, because I finally got around to adding drop down navigation to keep everything from getting cluttered. That worked great. But now I have run into a problem.

When I load the site on my S3 everything looks just like I expected. When I rotate to landscape though, the header and navigation show up, but all the page content is invisible. It is all there...I can "highlight" text I can't see and save images that don't display, but I can't see anything. I rotate back to portrait and everything displays normally.

The site is a single page design and uses jQuery to navigate through "pages" the only code there I changed to add functionality to the drop down...

```
// toggle nav
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function () {
     $("#nav").slideToggle();
});
```

and to hide the navigation when the menu-icon is visible

```
// When a nav link is clicked  
$("a.tab").click(function () {
    // Hide Nav menu if #menu-icon is visible
    if ($("#menu-icon").is(":visible")) {
         $("#nav").hide();
    }...
```

The only CSS changes I made were for styling the menu-icon, to hide it initially, and to display it in a media query...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/*Page Elements*/

#menu-icon 
{
    display: block;
    color:#bababa;
    font-size:1.5em;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2em;
    background:url(Images/Menu.png) no-repeat 5px center;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width:110px;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    border-radius:.35em;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em 2em;
}
```

So, my question is does anyone know what is going on with the disappearing content in landscape? Any help would be appreciated.

Oh yeah, everything is working fine on iPhones, desktop, iPads, etc.
And if it helps the site is http://tapricedesigns.com

Thanks in advance guys!

---

### **=======UPDATE========**

I isolated the problem in my media-queries. Apparently this behavior is being caused by a `position:relative` on the `header` that is added when I am re-positioning it to the top of the page. I have no idea why that is causing a problem when rotating the phone (maybe a weird bug?). I am going to try to create a media query that only targets the Galaxy S3 in landscape position and use `position:absolute` with some more styling rules on the content to keep the layout from breaking. I will update again once I get everything working right.

---

### **=======UPDATE 2========**

I got it resolved now. I didn't have `overflow:auto` on my container div so it wasn't wrapping the content after everything got re-positioned. I am still not completely sure why no `overflow:auto` was causing the `position:relative` on the `header` to break the display in Dolphin and Android Browser, but it works now, so I think I'll just quit while I am ahead. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested this with multiple browsers on your phone?

Comment: No, I just used the default browser. Thanks for the tip. I'll try some others out and see if they are working. Either way, I'd like it to work in the default browser too.

Comment: Ok, worked like a Charm in Firefox and Opera. Dolphin has the same behavior as the Android Browser.

Comment: I would try messing with the `overflow`, `whitespace` and `z-index` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you a valid and applicable **Answer**......

Please test in multiple browsers on the mobile.

Also, I would try adjusting the `overflow`, `whitespace` and `z-index` values of the main page content and the `float` value of the navigation menu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried messing around with the properties you suggested to no avail. I had some hope for maybe a `z-index` fix, but nothing seemed to work. Just to clarify, there are no problems with the layout. Everything appears to be rendering properly as far as layout goes, they just aren't actually displaying for some reason. So, if I hold down my finger where an image should be, the menu comes up to save, view, etc. but there is nothing actually displaying, same thing goes for text. It works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, but not in Dolphin or Android Browser.

Comment: So, you were right the whole time and I feel like a moron. The problem was that the container div didn't have `overflow:auto` and so it wasn't wrapping the page content when everything got re-positioned. Thanks for your help! Sorry, I didn't catch that sooner. Either way, invisible content seems like a weird response from Android and Dolphin. Thanks again!

Comment: @tadarice - just glad I could help! Never, ever expect two browsers to render the same output. They each have their quirks. Just do your best to develop uniformly and work out the snafus afterwards. :)